# How to find if my hardware supported by Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, performance, support

It is better to let make sure if **System can/will be worked effectively & efficiently.**

So, before installing Ubuntu, how can I find out if my **hardware** like motherboard components, graphics card, etc, are supported by **Ubuntu**?

Can I find through model or chipset or as better as possible?

Comment: Also, try booting in live mode.

Comment: @SylvainPineau from that question, answer with link - [hardware compatibility databases](http://linuxhcl.com/browse/search) not opening!.

Comment: Prefer the official list: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/

Comment: @SylvainPineau Can/please you post alternative official/better answer with some useful source/links?

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification

Answer (score 1):

Your best way to know if your hardware will work is to download ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) then burn the image and set your computer to boot from that image whether it is in livecd or liveusb format and run it in the try mode and see for yourself if your hardware works. You may have to install a driver for your wireless to work it all depends on your wireless card type.